# Determine the minimum value of the expression, for $a,b$ , $c$ $\in\ \textbf{R}^+$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be the positive real numbers. Determine the minimum value of $$\frac{a+3c}{a+2b+c} + \frac{4b}{a+b+2c} - \frac{8c}{a+b+3c}.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: With some help from Maple, the minimum value is 
$$-17 + 12\sqrt{2} \approx -0.02943725$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $a+2b+c=x$, $a+b+2c=y$ and $a+b+3c=z$.

Hence, $a=5y-x-3z$, $b=x-2y+z$, $c=z-y$ and by AM-GM
$$\frac{a+3c}{a+2b+c} + \frac{4b}{a+b+2c} - \frac{8c}{a+b+3c}=4\left(\frac{z}{y}+\frac{2y}{z}\right)+2\left(\frac{2x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right)-17\geq $$
$$\geq8\sqrt2+4\sqrt2-17=12\sqrt2-17.$$
The equality occurs for $\frac{z}{y}=\frac{2y}{z}$ and $\frac{2x}{y}=\frac{y}{x}$, which says that the equality indeed occurs.

Id est, the answer is $12\sqrt2-17$.

Comment: Never mind, just another type. Should be $\frac{z}{y}=\frac{2y}{z}$. So the example values should be $x=1,y=\sqrt{2},z=2$, and then $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: Thank you Thomas again! :)